# Using Javascript/JQuery to cycle Active class on Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I am in the process of developing a Bootstrap Carousel Module for a CMS I am using.

The issue I am having is that when the CMS is implementing the carousel using the images uploaded by the user, the active class is missing from the carousel item, therefore, it is not showing up to start with or cycling through the images.

```
<section class="image-carousel">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image1.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Caption goes here
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="item">
                <img src="image2.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Caption goes here
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="item">
                <img src="image3.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Caption goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to use Javascript/JQuery to add an active class to the first item, and then remove this class and add it to the next item in a given interval

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
//init some variables
var currentItem= 0;
var delay= parseInt($('#carousel').prop('data-interval'));
//set first item active
$('.carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');
//wait delay milliseconds to call nextItem function
setInterval(nextItem, delay);

function nextItem(){
  //increase index, and loop if necessary
  currentItem++;
  if (currentItem== $('.carousel-inner .item').length) currentItem= 0;
  //remove 'active' class from all items, and add it to the current one
  $('.carousel-inner .item').removeClass('active').eq(currentItem).addClass('active');
  //wait delay milliseconds to call this function again
  setInterval(nextItem, delay);

}
```

Comment: Cheers will try it asap and get back to you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to get it working by just using javascript to add an active class on the first item element using the document.ready.